# Apacite mess up whole document formatting

Tags: lyx, apacite

I've installed the apacite package from CTAN, so I can use BibTex for the full bibliography.

But at the top left corner, there is now two equal signs, as "==".

1. I can't seem to get it to work.
2. If I add the bibliography to my full thesis document in LyX the formatting is messed up.

Is there a simple solution? I'd be ever grateful!

I write the following in the preamble:

```
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{apacite}
\renewcommand{\bibsection}{}
```

All the best,
Christoffer

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. You haven't given nearly enough information for us to help you. But to start with, if you are loading `natbib` you need to load `apacite` with the `natbibapa` option. You also need to use the `apacite` bibliography style.  Instead of  showing a picture of your console output, it's more helpful to copy it into your question marked as code. But I suspect you may just need to delete your `.aux` files and recompile to get things to work.   And what are you trying to achieve by redefining `\bibsection`? This may the source of the problem in your header.

Comment: `natbib` and `apacite` are two separate and *mutually incompatible* citation management packages. Absolutely nothing good will come from loading both. As @AlanMunn - has already noted in a comment, `apacite` can be loaded with the option `natbibapa`; this allows users to use commands such as `\citet` and `\citep` to create citation call-outs.

Comment: @Mico Well not literally incompatible, since loading `apacite` with the `natbibapa` option loads `natbib`. But it's true that if you load `natbib` before `apacite` instead of using the `natbibapa` option you will get exactly the error in the console message.

Comment: @AlanMunn - the "separate and mutually incompatible" claim was meant to refer to the OP's act of loading the packages separately and independently of each other. Sorry that this wasn't clear. My bad. As you note, executing `\usepackage[natbibapa]{natbib}` modifies the code of the `apacite` package suitably in order to remove the incompatibilities with `natbib`.

Comment: Hi @AlanMunn and @ Mico. Appreciate both of your answers. I've added apacite to the bibliography style and it now runs. The error message does say, "LaTeX Error: Unknown option 'natbibapa' for package 'natbib'. But the output works now. Thank you. 

@ Alan Munn the redefining \bicsection was to remove "References" from the output - I couldn't find another way to do so, but I found the solution in another thread. Appreciate your help!

Comment: We both could have been clearer (@mico mistyped in his previous comment.). The proper way to do this is to not load `natbib` at all and let `apacite` do it with `\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}`